# Airline plugin configuration

Tags: plugin-airline

I've installed the [airline plugin](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) and I find it useful. However, I'd like to customize it a bit to look like that:
[image: vim-airline]

I'm not talking about the theme (it's gruvbox) I'm talking about how the different sections are separated. 
In the image, they're are like arrows but in my terminal they're rectangles.
Is it something with my terminal?
[image: My vim-airline]

Edit:

From the README

> For the nice looking powerline symbols to appear, you will need to install a patched font. Instructions can be found in the official powerline documentation. Prepatched fonts can be found in the powerline-fonts repository.

I didn't think the "nice looking powerline symbols" made reference to the shape of the separators too.

Anyway, it works nice now. Thanks

Comment: It's there in the README: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline#integrating-with-powerline-fonts